NPSP Household Address Issue
We have an issue with NPSP Household Account and contact data. We do not want to sync newly created contact addresses to the Household account and all contact addresses. We know we can stop it by setting the Contact > Address Override field to True.
In our case, if we have a contact without an address (address is blank/null), we want to keep it blank, and we do not want to sync this blank address to the Household address. The issue arises when we add a new contact without an address (null address), as it syncs this blank address to the Household address, making it blank and updating all related contacts' addresses as blank where Address Override = False.
If we try to manually or automatically set the address to blank on this new contact with Address Override = True, it shows an error and does not work. Our main goal is to keep the new contact address blank without any changes to the respective Household account address.
Error Screenshot when we are trying to make contact Address blank:

